# What's wrong with this ternary operator?

Tags: php, css, ternary

I use a paging system like this:

```
<?php
$p = $_GET['p'];

switch($p)
{
    case "start":
        $p = "pages/start.php";
        $currentPageId = 1;
    break;

    case "customers":
        $p = "pages/customers.php";
        $currentPageId = 2;
    break;

    default:
        $p = "pages/start.php";
        $currentPageId = 1;
    break;
}
?>
```

I want to set css `class="active"` to the menu item of the page i'm on.
It works if I print `<li>` items like this:

```
<li><a href="?p=start" <?php if ($currentPageId == 1) {echo "class='active'";}else {} ?>>Start</a></li>
```

But I would like to use ternary operator instead. I tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
<li><a href="?p=start" <?php ($currentPageId == '1') ? 'class="active"' : '' ?>>Startsida</a></li>
```

Any idea why?

**EDIT**
So the problem was I was missing an `echo`. Now let me extend the question a bit...
I need to encapsulate my entire `<ul>` inside the `<?php ?>` tags. So what I would like is something like this:

```
echo "<div id='nav'>";
 echo "<ul>";

   echo "<li><a href='?p=start' /* ternary operator to match if the page I'm on is equal to $currentPageId as defined in the paging system (above), if so set class='active' else do nothing*/>Start</a></li>;
   echo "<li><a href='?p=customers' /* ternary operator to match if the page I'm on is equal to $currentPageId as defined in the paging system (above), if so set class='active' else do nothing*/>Customers</a></li>;


 echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";
```

I need to do this because I will display the links based on `if`statements.. "if user is admin display this link, else don't" ... Anyone got a solution?

Comment: Because you don't have an `echo`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing an echo:

```
<li><a href="?p=start" <?php echo (($currentPageId == '1') ? 'class="active"' : '') ?>>Startsida</a></li>
```

That should do the trick.

---

Addressing the second question:

```
<?php
if($something == true) {
    echo "<div id='nav'>"."\n<br>".
            "<ul>"."\n<br>".
                '<li><a href="?p=start"'. (($currentPageId == '1') ? 'class="active"' : '') .'>Startsida</a></li>'."\n<br>".
                '<li><a href="?p=customers" '. (($currentPageId == '1') ? 'class="active"' : '') .' >Customers</a></li>'."\n<br>".
            "</ul>"."\n<br>".
            "</div>"."\n<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I have another question for you. What if I would like to `echo` out the entire `<li>`element with the ternary included. How would I do this? I'm new to PHP..

Comment: You mean something like this? <?php echo (($currentPageId == '1') ? '<li><a href="?p=start" class="active">Startsida</a></li>' : '') ?>

Comment: Not really. I'm trying to echo the entire `<ul> <li>` within PHP so I wonder if it's possible to do something like this: `echo "<li><a href='?p=start' /*ternary operator here */ >Start</a></li>"`

Comment: @David ...as per link above, look at example #6 on that page. Might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @Fred Thank's for the suggestion but it seems way out of my league to make that work.

Comment: You should post your entire <ul> block, otherwise it's hard to tell what you want to echo :)

Comment: @David Try some of the examples out to get a feel of it. No better way to learn, than by making `mistakes`. As the saying goes "Show me someone who's never made a mistake, and I'll show you someone who hasn't learned anything. You're not gonna break anything ;-)

Comment: @David Basically, you `echo` anything between `echo <<<'EOT' and EOT;` EOT being any matching placemarker name, but the names must match.

Comment: Answer updated, hopefully it is what you were looking for. Also next time you should probably open a new question instead.

Comment: No problem, but make sure the destination of these links also check whether the user is admin or not; simply hiding the links to non-admins won't make it secure by itself. Just saying in case you didn't consider this.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you were missing echo. I also wanted to point out that you don't even need a ternary operator in this case because you aren't doing anything in the else case:

```
<li><a href="?p=start" <?php if ($currentPageId == '1') echo 'class="active"'; ?>>Startsida</a></li>
```