# Hide content on a sidebar depending on the page

Tags: php, html, css, show-hide, sidebar

I have a website with the following setup:

overview.php
hotel1.php
hotel2.php
hotel3.php

Where overview has a sidebar with links to hotels 1, 2 and 3 and each hotel page has a sidebar with links to the other two hotels (excluding itself) along with the overview page.

At the minute, I am hard coding the sidebar in each php page, as they are all slightly different.

I am wondering if there is a way I can code one sidebar in a separate file (sidebar.php) with links to each of the four pages and add the sidebar with a php include() function.

Then, depending on the page (which will have an identifier), show all the links, except the link to itself.

Problem is, I'm not sure how to do it, or if it can be done.

The site is php and html (with css and javascript).

And if it is relevant, I have about 100 folders containing an overview and then multiple hotels which I would like to implement this on.

Comment: create a seperate file (sidebar.php) then in hotels.php file (which hotel file you want sidebar to show) the you include sidebar.php

Comment: You could use something to the affect of `if ($currentPageId == 1) {echo "class='active'";}else {}` and use a CSS class for the item(s) you wish to hide. In conjunction with a `switch` and `case`. I have this in my menu files when I found this question/answer on SO. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11075949/1415724

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to wrap your sidebar code in a function.

sidebar.php

```
<?php
    function print_all_sidebar_links_except_self($self = NULL){
        $hotels_text = array(
            "hotel1" => "Gryffindor Tower",
            "hotel2" => "Ravenclaw Tower",
            "hotel3" => "Slytherin Dungeons"
        );

        if (isset($self)){
            unset($hotels_text[$self]);
        }

        foreach ($hotels_text as $page => $name){
            echo "<a href='".$page.".php'>".$name."</a>";
        }
    }
?>
```

- overview.php: `print_all_sidebar_links_except_self()`;
- hotel1.php: `print_all_sidebar_links_except_self('hotel1');`
- hotel2.php: `print_all_sidebar_links_except_self('hotel2');`
- hotel3.php: `print_all_sidebar_links_except_self('hotel3');`

Comment: *"Hide content on a sidebar depending on the page"* – Where does the hiding come into effect?

Comment: On my old code, the if's checked for itself and then skipped the echo. I refactored my code to make it more extensible, and it should be clear now. The "hiding" involves not passing it to the user at all.

Comment: Ah ok, this makes sense to me now.

Comment: `+1` on code and choice of "hotels". Just not sure if I'd want to stay at the "Slytherin Dungeons" though ;-)

Comment: Hm, I think you're right; I don't think they like us Muggles very much.

Comment: LOL! Depending on what a "Muggle" is! I'd say I would rather play it safe myself ;-)